# XML is invalid error while running psquery

Tags: peoplesoft

We are getting `XML is invalid` error while running PSQuery. This message occurs when we have more than one required fields in the PSQuery and we select value only for one of them and leave the rest blank. In such cases, instead of giving an error message `field is required`. But, PSQuery still gives the message `xml is invalid`.

Comment: Hello , what's your Peopletools version ?